# Why isn't WPF showing my tree structured data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

Here is my XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.FeatureExplorerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Morris.FeatureExplorer"
             xmlns:state="clr-namespace:Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             local:VsTheme.UseVSTheme="true"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label>Top</Label>
        <TreeView Name="ProjectTree">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type state:ProjectTreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFolders}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <Label>Bottom</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code-behind

```cs
using Fluxor;
using Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer;

partial class FeatureExplorerControl : UserControl, IDisposable
{
    private bool IsDisposed;
    private IState<FeaturesState> State;

    public FeatureExplorerControl(IState<FeaturesState> state)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        State = state;
        State.StateChanged += State_StateChanged;
        RecreateViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (IsDisposed) return;
        State.StateChanged -= State_StateChanged;
        IsDisposed = true;
    }

    private void State_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateViewModel();    
    }

    private void RecreateViewModel()
    {
        DataContext = State.Value?.Root ?? ProjectTreeNode.Empty;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, my RecreateViewModel is executed with an empty state, so nothing to show. Afterwards, it is executed again and has a valid set of tree structured data, but the UI is not displaying it.

This is the JSON serialized representation of my data

```json
{
  "Name": "",
  "ParentPath": "",
  "ChildFolders": [
    {
      "Name": "Person",
      "ParentPath": "",
      "ChildFolders": [
        {
          "Name": "PersonSubFolder1",
          "ParentPath": "Person",
          "ChildFolders": [],
          "Files": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "PersonSubFolder2",
          "ParentPath": "Person",
          "ChildFolders": [],
          "Files": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "PersonSubFolder3",
          "ParentPath": "Person",
          "ChildFolders": [],
          "Files": []
        }
      ],
      "Files": [
        {
          "ProjectName": "ConsoleApp123",
          "ParentPath": "Person",
          "FilePath": "FeaturesX\\Person\\PersonUI.cs",
          "FileExtension": ".cs",
          "FileName": "PersonUI.cs"
        },
        {
          "ProjectName": "ClassLibrary1",
          "ParentPath": "Person",
          "FilePath": "FeaturesX\\Person\\PersonModel.cs",
          "FileExtension": ".cs",
          "FileName": "PersonModel.cs"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Files": []
}
```

The classes are as follows.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store;

public sealed class ProjectFileInfo : IEquatable<ProjectFileInfo>
{
    public string ProjectName { get; }
    public string ParentPath { get; }
    public string FilePath { get; }
    public string FileExtension { get; }
    public string FileName { get; }

    private Lazy<int> LazyGetHashCode;

    public ProjectFileInfo(string projectName, string parentPath, string filePath)
    {
        ProjectName = projectName;
        ParentPath = parentPath;
        FilePath = filePath;
        FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        LazyGetHashCode = new Lazy<int>(() => HashCode.Combine(ProjectName, ParentPath, filePath));
    }

    public bool Equals(ProjectFileInfo other) =>
        other.ProjectName == ProjectName
        && other.ParentPath == ParentPath
        && other.FilePath == FilePath;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
         obj is ProjectFileInfo projectFile && Equals(projectFile);

    public override int GetHashCode() => LazyGetHashCode.Value;

    public override string ToString() => $"{ProjectName}\\{ParentPath}\\{FileName}";
}

using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store;

public sealed class ProjectFolderInfo : IEquatable<ProjectFolderInfo>
{
    public string ParentPath { get; }
    public string FolderName { get; }
    public string FullPath { get; }
    public string LayerName { get; }

    private Lazy<int> LazyGetHashCode;

    public ProjectFolderInfo(
        string parentPath,
        string folderName,
        string layerName)
    {
        FolderName = folderName;
        ParentPath = parentPath;
        FullPath = Path.Combine(parentPath, folderName);
        LayerName = layerName;

        LazyGetHashCode = new Lazy<int>(() =>
            HashCode.Combine(
                ParentPath,
                FolderName,
                LayerName));
    }

    public bool Equals(ProjectFolderInfo other) =>
        other.ParentPath == ParentPath
        && other.FolderName == FolderName
        && other.LayerName == LayerName;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
         obj is ProjectFolderInfo projectFolder && Equals(projectFolder);

    public override int GetHashCode() => LazyGetHashCode.Value;

    public override string ToString() => $"{ParentPath}\\{FolderName}";
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store;

public sealed class ProjectTreeNode : IEquatable<ProjectTreeNode>
{
    public static readonly ProjectTreeNode Empty = new("", "");

    public string Name { get; }
    public string ParentPath { get; }
    public ImmutableArray<ProjectTreeNode> ChildFolders { get; }
    public ImmutableArray<ProjectFileInfo> Files { get; }

    private Lazy<int> LazyGetHashCode;

    public ProjectTreeNode(
        string name,
        string parentPath,
        ImmutableArray<ProjectTreeNode>? childFolders = null,
        ImmutableArray<ProjectFileInfo>? files = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        ParentPath = parentPath;
        ChildFolders = childFolders.GetNotNullOrDefault();
        Files = files.GetNotNullOrDefault();

        LazyGetHashCode = new Lazy<int>(() =>
            HashCode.Combine(
                Name,
                ParentPath,
                ChildFolders.GetContentsHashCode(),
                Files.GetContentsHashCode()));
    }

    public bool Equals(ProjectTreeNode other) =>
        other.Name == Name
        && other.ParentPath == ParentPath
        && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ChildFolders, other.ChildFolders)
        && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(Files, other.Files);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
         obj is ProjectTreeNode projectFolder && Equals(projectFolder);

    public override int GetHashCode() => LazyGetHashCode.Value;

    public override string ToString() => $"{ParentPath}\\{Name}";
}

using Fluxor;

namespace Morris.FeatureExplorer.Features.FeatureExplorer.Store;

[FeatureState]
public record class FeaturesState
{
    public static readonly FeaturesState Empty =
        new FeaturesState
        { 
            Root = ProjectTreeNode.Empty
        };

    public ProjectTreeNode Root { get; init; }
};
```